# Unicode chars are converted to broken symbols when I use wkhtmltopdf

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, cjk, wkhtmltopdf

I have HTML that contains some Unicode characters, and saved in "UTF-8" to disk. I can use less to display it, all characters displayed well:

```
<h1>什么是Action?</h1>
<p>Play程序接收到的大部分请求，都是由<code>Action</code>来处理的。
```

But when I use "wkhtmltopdf" to convert it to PDF, it shows broken characters:

[image: broken unicode]

My command is:

```
wkhtmltopdf --encoding utf-8 book.html book.pdf
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I found the reason: I don't have unicode fonts in my ubuntu server.

I upload some truetype fonts from my local ubuntu to the server, everything works fine.

```
freewind@freewind:/usr/share/fonts$ cd truetype/
freewind@freewind:/usr/share/fonts/truetype$ ls
arphic             ttf-dejavu               ttf-lao
freefont           ttf-devanagari-fonts     ttf-liberation
kochi              ttf-gujarati-fonts       ttf-malayalam-fonts
msttcorefonts      ttf-indic-fonts-core     ttf-oriya-fonts
openoffice         ttf-japanese-gothic.ttf  ttf-punjabi-fonts
sazanami           ttf-japanese-mincho.ttf  ttf-tamil-fonts
takao              ttf-kacst-one            ttf-telugu-fonts
thai               ttf-kannada-fonts        unfonts
ttf-bengali-fonts  ttf-khmeros-core         wqy
```

I simply upload them all, it fix this problem, although I don't know which font is the key.

Comment: As a last resort, you could use the `Code 2000` font that has plenty of glyphs -- one of the more complete Unicode font out there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code2000

Comment: Accept this as the answer as it fixed the problem. I struggled with this for a while and it was because I was writing (source html) files without a proper encoding `new StreamWriter(this.path, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)` - there are lots of different reasons why this might fail :)

Comment: I have also solved this the same way but on centos. Just copied `Arial.ttf` from my local mac in `/Library/Fonts` to my remote server to `/usr/share/fonts/local` (created the `local` dir myself). then `fc-cache -v` to update and it worked

Comment: I am having same problem to convert website http://www.odialanguage.com/. I have tried by importing fonts also. Can you please help to identify what I am missing

Comment: Installing the `Code 2000` font did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem too. Turned out, the HTML file had a `meta` tag that was setting the wrong `charset`. 
Eg the HTML file had

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style>
```

and the issue was resolved when I switched it to instead `utf-8` for the charset, like so:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
```

Comment: yes this fixed it for me too, I had simply not defined the charset

Answer (score 0):

Try
    wkhtmltopdf-i386 book.html book.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a MS Windows machine (the above answer is for X Windows font server), the following worked for me:

1. You can use YaHei or SimSun with wkhtmltoimage.
2. Explicitly set content using Chinese letters to the new font-family in your style:

   ```
   .smsnotification_chinese {
       font-size: 30px;    
       font-family: "Microsoft Yahei", SimSun;
   }
   ```

   This will work on stock US Windows machines. There is a more robust description of font fallbacks described here for others: [Chinese Standard Web Fonts: A Guide to CSS Font Family Declarations for Web Design in Simplified Chinese](http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/).
3. **Note:** The wkhtmltoimage binary does not work on Azure worker machines due to GDI+ sandbox restrictions. You can get around this by writing your own web service wrapper or using this free wrapper: [Convert HTML to PDF in .Net on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642451/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net-on-azure/26291022#26291022)